# Maxima: convert matrix to list

Tags: symbolic-math, maxima, computer-algebra-systems

I convert list to matrix in Maxima in following way:

```
DataL : [ [1,2], [2,4], [3,6], [4,8] ];
DataM: apply('matrix,DataL);
```

How to do it the other way ? How to convert given matrix *DataM* into list *DataL* ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I know it's late in the game, but for what it's worth, there is a simpler way.

```
my_matrix : matrix ([a, b, c], [d, e, f]);
my_list : args (my_matrix);
 => [[a, b, c], [d, e, f]]
```

Comment: @Grzegorz Can you move the checkmark to Robert's answer, as it seems to be the more reasonable way of doing things.

Comment: @Simon Fair point - Just did. However, I can't recall why, because I was writing longer Maxima script, in my case your solution worked better or was more convenient. Anyway - tick moved. Thanks both of you for help, Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

I'm far from a Maxima expert, but since [you asked me to look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662477/maxima-simplify-matrix-components/7694861#comment-10936445), here's what I have after a quick look through the [documentation](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima.html).

First, looking at the [documentation on matrices](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_23.html) yielded only one way of turning matrices in to lists, which is `list_matrix_entries`. However, this returns a flat list of the entries. To get a nested list structure, something like the following works

```
DataL : [[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 6], [4, 8]];  /* Using your example list */
DataM : apply('matrix, DataL);              /* and matrix             */

DataML : makelist(list_matrix_entries(row(DataM, i)), i, 1, 4);
is(DataML = DataL);   /*  true  */
```

This is clumsy and probably inefficient. Using the underlying Lisp structure in Maxima (and analogy to Mathematica, which I'm more familiar with) you can examine the heads of `DataL` and `DataM` using [part](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_6.html#part):

```
part(DataL, 0);  /*  [       */
part(DataM, 0);  /*  matrix  */
```

Then to convert between the two structures, you can use [substpart](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_6.html#substpart)

```
is(substpart(matrix, DataL, 0) = DataM);   /*  true  */
is(substpart( "[",   DataM, 0) = DataL);   /*  true  */
```

Using `substpart` at level `0` is almost the same as using [`apply`](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_36.html#apply), except it works on more than just lists.

Comment: Thank you @Simon . Your solution works great. I've been walking forward and backward documentation with no success. As I use least squares method and few others operating on different types (some restricts to matrix, while others operates on lists) two way conversion is big help.